# In need of a query logic, how to group by id from the users table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
INSERT INTO `companies` (`name`) VALUES
('Walmart'),
('Disney'),
('Amazon'),
('Unicom'),
('Microsoft'),
('Intel')

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `company`) VALUES
(1, 'Disney'),
(2, 'Amazon'),
(3, 'Intel'),
(3, 'Walmart'),
(4, 'Microsoft'),
(4, 'Unicom'),
(5, 'Microsoft')
```

The result should be following:

```
1. 'Walmart', 'Amazon', 'Unicom', 'Microsoft', 'Intel'
2. 'Walmart', 'Disney', 'Unicom', 'Microsoft', 'Intel'
3. 'Disney', 'Amazon', 'Unicom', 'Microsoft'
4. 'Walmart', 'Disney', 'Amazon', 'Intel'
5. 'Walmart', 'Disney', 'Amazon', 'Unicom', 'Intel'
```

I have tried with:

```
"SELECT a.name, b.id, b.company FROM users RIGHT JOIN companies ON b.company <> a.name"
```

This gives the correct logic by omitting the company name that's already on the list but the problem is that it processes the same id twice and omits a different company name. How would one approach this query?

Comment: That is a strange table design. What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea in the query below is to left join a calendar table containing every possible user/company combination to the `users` table.  Those combinations which *do* match are removed, and the remaining companies are then rolled up into a CSV string for each user using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT u.id, c.name
    FROM users u
    CROSS JOIN companies c
) t1
LEFT JOIN users t2
    ON t1.name = t2.company AND t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.company IS NULL
GROUP BY
    t1.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT a.name, b.id, b.company FROM users RIGHT JOIN companies ON b.company <> a.name group by b.company"
```